# Why Won't This Generic Method Call Compile?

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I an enum, which extends short:

```
public enum EnumType : short
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2
}
```

Then I have a utility method that looks like this:

```
public static class EnumUtilities
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TEnum, TBase>> GetTuples<TEnum, TBase>()
        where TEnum : struct, TBase
    {
        return GetValues<TEnum>().Select(x => new Tuple<TEnum, TBase>(x, x));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>() where T : struct
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
    }
}
```

When I try to call it, I get a compilation error saying "The Type EnumType must be convertible to 'short' in order to use it as parameter 'TEnum' in the generic method 'IEnumerable> GetTuples()'

I'm having trouble understanding how it is that EnumType is not convertible to 'short' when it is defined to extend 'short.'  I'm also not understanding how the following compiles, but the above example does not.  Any help appreciated!

```
var enumType = EnumType.Value1;
var value1 = (short)enumType;
```

Comment: `Enum` by default is of type `int`. So implicit conversion to `short` is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that in the `GetTuples<,>()`generic method constraints You wrote

```
TEnum: struct, TBase
```

which means that `TEnum` should be derived type from `TBase`. I suppose You tried to call it more or less like this: `EnumUtilities.GetTuples<EnumType, short>()`. **The thing is, the `EnumType` is not derived from `short`.**

The way You declared it:

```
public enum EnumType: short
{ ... }
```

means just that `short` should be used for this enumeration as an underlying type to represent its enumeration members. All enumeration types are derived from `Enum` class, so calling `GetTuples<EnumType, short>` will not compile using the code You provided, but `GetTuples<EnumType, Enum>` will compile.

That's why Your sample does not work as You intended.

You can fix the `GetTuples<,>()` method by removing the inheritance constraint and checking the underlying type at runtime:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TEnum, TBase>> GetTuples<TEnum, TBase>()
       where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    Type tEnumType = typeof(TEnum);
    if (!tEnumType.IsEnum || Enum.GetUnderlyingType(tEnumType) != typeof(TBase))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type specified.");
    }
    return GetValues<TEnum>().Select(x => new Tuple<TEnum, TBase>(x, (TBase)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(TBase))));
}
```

Now You should be able to call `EnumUtilities.GetTuples<EnumType, short>();` and it should compile correctly.

The disadvantage of this solution is that runtime check is less efficient than using compile-time constraint.

Comment: This was the key to understanding, of course :)

"The thing is, the EnumType is not derived from short."

Answer (score 0):

Your EnumType is inheriting from short, which is by default from Enum, so casting EnumType value to short explictly, while using it works fine. Another way is to convert values to short at the time of initialisation, as below.

```
public enum EnumType : short
{
    Value1 = (short)1,
    Value2 = (short)2
}
```

In this case, don't need to cast at the time of using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static class EnumUtilities
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TEnum, object>> GetTuples<TEnum>() where TEnum :    struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
           throw new Exception("wrong!");

        return GetValues<TEnum>().Select(x => new Tuple<TEnum, object>(x, Convert.ChangeType(x, x.GetTypeCode())));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
         if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            throw new Exception("wrong!");

         return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
    }
}
```